# read all data from google fit server using History API

Tags: google-fit

I develop a Google Fit application with Fit API for Android. I have the same google account in two devices but I can not read all the data aggregated from my application. I only read the data aggregated from the own device. I try to explain with an example:

Device A add Activity A and only read Activity A
Device B add Activity B and only read Activity B

I want to read Activity A and B in the device. I use History API for write and read the data. I try to use Recording API with subscription, add enableServerQueries, read() and aggregate()  to DataReadRequest but nothing.

This is  my code for read from the History API:

> readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
>   .read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT).enableServerQueries()
>        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

```
   Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(MainActivity.mClient, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT);
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Inicializado dataRead, limite:" + d.getLimit());
        DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(MainActivity.mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        printData(dataReadResult);
```

Can you help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Check how you initialize your callbacks and your subscription. Check if both device have the same subscription in order, this enables your app to sync with data from other devices, and also allows for the passive recording of data on the device. Also remember to check how your code write to the subscription. Here is a [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-fit-for-android-recording-api--cms-25855) that discuss how to use Google Fit for Android: Recording API. Hope this information helps!

Comment: Thank you for you replay!  I try to do all operations with History API and only use subscription in this part (code in my ask) because I read that is necessary in other sites. Can I do this without Recording API? I am going to do your recommendations. I tell you with news ;)

Comment: Hi @Mr.Rebot I modified my app with the tutorial but not working : ( . I use the initCallback and added to the subscribe and unsubscribe. I use buildFitnessClient how the example of google fit. Thank you